# How to reference Domain-Admins with icacls?

Tags: windows, scripting, batch, domain-name-system

I need to reference the "Domain-Admins" group in a batch file. The line in question looks like this:

```
icacls "test\folder" /grant mydomain.com\Domain-Admins:F
```

... and works as expected.

But how do I reference the "Domain-Admin" group in general? My german windows server tells me something about "Domänen-Admins", the Italians call ist "Amministratore-Admins" (or whatever) and I dont want to know what the russian Domain Admins call themselves. I did not want to offend any international names, there must just be a solution for a generic adressing of roles. I need a solution for everybody - like Microsoft had in mind (hopefully) when they used SIDs.

I know the SID of the domain admin group looks like S-1-5-21mydomainsid-512, but icacls does not understand S-1-5-21*-512.

How do I use icacls wisely when I need to reference international group names?

Comment: ask yourself first how you ask wisely to an international group of people. And, no, I am not italian.

Comment: You are right, I am very sorry. I did not want to offend anyone (especially italians in this case). Again,s orry for this (and thanks PA for pointing this out to me). I do know that different countrys have their own names (for groups here) and I am (very) angry over my own stupidity to 'catch' the SID-concept in icacls. Dou you have an idea about how to handle international names in batch files? (or how to use SID-MAsks correctly in icacls)

Comment: I have a english domain and a dutch client. On this client I can use "mydomain\domain admins" (between quotes and with a space) without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to grant by SID with icacls. Microsoft [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753525%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) even has an example granting permissions by SID.

Is each international locale a different domain/sid? You would need to add the sid or icacls separately for each domain into the batch file.

Comment: I think the OP may be trying to use a wildcard "*" in the SID?

Comment: Yes, wildcards are the thing I need (I think). SIDs with wildcards like *S-1-1-0: do work, but not if the wildcard is -in- the SID´, like S-1-*-0:. The Domain-SID is the middle part of the complete SID (following the documentation), so wildcard do not work here (in icacls).

Comment: Every domain has its very own SID and this script should work in a lot (if not all :-) of them.